# Adding row in jquery-datatables-editable plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, row, jeditable

I'm using the plugin [this](http://jquery-datatables-editable.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/addingrecords.html) for Adding a new record. In this example while clicking 'Add' Button, a subform opens with the fields in the table. And on clicking ok in the subform a new editable row is created in the table with the values mentioned in subform.
But I need to add a editable row without opening the subform. And the user has to enter the values in the table. 
This code is used to add a row from the subform in "jquery.dataTables.editable.js" file.

```
///Event handler called when a new row is added and response is returned from server
        function _fnOnRowAdded(data) {
            properties.fnEndProcessingMode();

            if (properties.fnOnNewRowPosted(data)) {

                var oSettings = oTable.fnSettings();
                var iColumnCount = oSettings.aoColumns.length;
                var values = new Array();

                $("input:text[rel],input:radio[rel][checked],input:hidden[rel],select[rel],textarea[rel],span.datafield[rel]", oAddNewRowForm).each(function () {
                    var rel = $(this).attr("rel");
                    var sCellValue = "";
                    if (rel >= iColumnCount)
                        properties.fnShowError("In the add form is placed input element with the name '" + $(this).attr("name") + "' with the 'rel' attribute that must be less than a column count - " + iColumnCount, "add");
                    else {
                        if (this.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "select" || this.tagName.toLowerCase() == "select")
                            sCellValue = $("option:selected", this).text();
                        else if (this.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "span" || this.tagName.toLowerCase() == "span")
                            sCellValue = $(this).html();
                        else
                            sCellValue = this.value;

                        sCellValue = sCellValue.replace(properties.sIDToken, data);
                        values[rel] = sCellValue;
                    }
                });

                //Add values from the form into the table
                var rtn = oTable.fnAddData(values);
                var oTRAdded = oTable.fnGetNodes(rtn);
                //Apply editable plugin on the cells of the table
                _fnApplyEditable(oTRAdded);
                //add id returned by server page as an TR id attribute
                properties.fnSetRowID($(oTRAdded), data);
                //Close the dialog
                oAddNewRowForm.dialog('close');
                $(oAddNewRowForm)[0].reset();
                $(".error", $(oAddNewRowForm)).html("");

                _fnSetDisplayStart();
                properties.fnOnAdded("success");
            }
        }
```

I edited the above code to add a row without open the subform. But the added row is not editable. What changes should i do to make it editable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use fnAddData to add rows and then make that row editable. Here's an [example](http://datatables.net/examples/api/editable.html) which shows how to make the row editable.

Untested code to add a row(taken from the jquery datatables docs)

```
var giCount = 2;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').dataTable();
} );

function fnClickAddRow() {
  $('#example').dataTable().fnAddData( [
    giCount+".1",
    giCount+".2",
    giCount+".3",
    giCount+".4" ]
  );

  giCount++;
}
```

EDIT 2: Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GrfPB/6/).

```
var oTable = $("table").dataTable();

$("a").click(function() {
    $(oTable).dataTable().fnAddData( ["test"] );
});

$('td', oTable.fnGetNodes()).editable(function(v, s) {
    console.log(v);
    return (v);
});
```

Note that you will require [jEditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) for this.

Cheers!

Comment: I have already tried "DataTables editing example". There is a problem. If i edit an element,editable_ajax.php is being called to update the record in server. What i want to do is to update the record only when the user submit the form, until then the changes made should be displayed in browser.

Comment: If you check the fiddle link above, when you edit the cells they do not get submitted. Basically i removed the ajax call.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/GrfPB/5/. I tried this . But after editing the text 'main' I'm getting error. The edit is not correct. And another one The newly added row is not editable.

Comment: after editing this row am getting this value in this row.
"{"error": "Shell form does not validate{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_lib', 'form': , 'html_name': 'js_lib', 'label': u'Js lib', 'field': , 'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_lib'}"}"

Comment: check the new fiddle link. :)

Comment: Editing is working fine :) but the adding new row script makes a problem. 
$("a").click(function() {
    $(oTable).dataTable().fnAddData(["test","hi","hi","hi","hi"]);
    $(oTable).find('td').editable(function(v, s) {
        console.log(v);
        return (v);
    });
});​
if i added this code , even table settings also is not working. some problem in this script. Should i add any source file to do this ?

Comment: you will have to have the same number of columns in the header also.
Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/GrfPB/8/)